# Enable cache for load function

Tags: javascript, jquery, caching

I have this code for loading a page in another :

```
$(".container").load(url, function () {
                       // do stuff
                    });
```

When this code executes, all of GET requests has `_={timestamp}` at the end of their links, like this : `http://localhost:2208/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.min.js?_=1399788658418`

I want to enable cache for my requests, also i need this only for this line.
I searching for some solutions and i guess using `ajaxSetup` do this, but i need to enable only for 1 request in my website.
What's your idea?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `$.ajax()` if you want to use extra settings.

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  dataType: 'html',
  success: function (data) {
    $(".container").html(data);

    // do stuff
  },
  cache: false
});
```